# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, assembly-binding-redirect

I got error massage like this:

> *An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   StarterMVC6.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)*

[Error after debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISZdn.jpg)

I started  with `New Project>ASP.NET Web.Application (.NET Framework) [.NET Framework 4.6] >>MVC with Individual user Accounts.`

After project was crated try to Debug project and get this massage above.

1. I try to resolve the problem with updating VS2015 with update 3, and
   ASP.NET web Tools, but the error is still here.
2. Then try to remove Microsoft.Owin and all his dependencies, and
   install it again, but that also didn’t solved the problem.
3. Try to make some changes in web.config file which I was found in
   several similar questions here on stackoverflow, but that also
   didn’t help, error is still persist.
4. After that I tray to uninstall VS2015 completely with
   [MicrosoftVisualStudio/TotalUninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases) This was quite good,
   removed all VS2015 dependencies.
5. Of course, I made fresh installation of VS2015 with all updates, but
   the problem still persist.

Now I am on the death end, just don’t know what to tray/do next.

This is web.config:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

Please Help!

Comment: Find out where in your program the exception is being thrown, then work from there. Also consider changing your question title to attract more attention - as it is right now no one has a clue what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for tip, i will do it right now.

Comment: Accidentally i found solution for this problem. I don't know how and why problem was solved after i change folder and sub-folder structure. Actually i had too much sub folders.